# Unable to get Three20 script working (ttmodule.py problem)

Tags: iphone

Forgive the newbie, but I have been searching for an answer for this for a week or so and starting to give up all hope.

I wanted to use the Three20 project to learn some more about iphone app dev.

I downloaded all the Three20 files via git and was using the script to place all the files in my latest project.

The following script:

> python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/myProject.xcodeproj Three20

Keeps giving me the following error:

Ricks-Mac:three20 rickyfarr5$ python src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p ../iphonedev/radviewer/viewer/viewer.xcodeproj Three20
ERROR:root:Unable to open the project file at this path (is it readable?): ../iphonedev/radviewer/viewer/viewer.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
ERROR:root:Unable to open the project file at this path (is it readable?): ../iphonedev/radviewer/viewer/viewer.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
ERROR:root:Failed to get dependencies.

The project.pbxproj file does exist and is readable

Where am I going wrong?

Hope someone can help.  Cheers.  Rick.

(Using xcode 3.2.5, iOS4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.... Bad file path! D'oh!